# Why $H=\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[n^{-1}, n^{-1}+2^{-n}\right]$ is a ball closed $G_\delta$ set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was reading [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-44/issue-2/A-topological-lemma-and-applications-to-real-functions/pjm/1102947974.full), when in the first page (Definition $1$) I found this claim:

> In $\left[0,1\right]$, $H=\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[n^{-1}, n^{-1}+2^{-n}\right]$ is a ball closed $G_\delta$ set that is not closed because it does not contain a $0$.

The paper defines a "ball closed $G_\delta$ set" as so:

> **Definition:** A $G_\delta$ subset $H$ of $K$ will be called a *ball closed $G_\delta$ set* if, whenever $B(x,r) \subseteq H$, $\{y \in K \mid |x-y|=r \} \subseteq H$.

However if I considered the ball $B_{(1/4, 1/4)}$, it is contained in $H$, but its border is not contained in $H$. So $H$ should not be considered ball closed!

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: FYI, I clicked on the paper's link out of curiosity, and actually recognized it, which is somewhat unusual for me for papers cited here or in mathoverflow. In fact, the author is my mathematical grandfather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general proof as to why $H$ is a ball closed $G_\delta$ set:

Firstly, notice that $K \setminus H =$ {$0, 1$} $\cup \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{1}{n})$. Suppose that $B(x, r) \subseteq H$, and that $y \in K$ such that $|x - y| = r$. Now, if $y \not\in H$, then we know there exists an integer $n \geq 1$ such that $y \in (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{1}{n})$ (assuming $y \neq 0, 1$, if $y = 0$ then $B(x, r) = B(x, x) = (0, 2x)$ which clearly is not contained in $H$). But it is clear that there exists $z \in (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{1}{n})$ such that $|x - z| < r$ (depending on the choice of $y$, since it can be $x - r$ or $x + r$ provided they are in $K$, one can choose $z > y$ on former case and $z < y$ on latter case). That is to say, $z \in B(x, r)$ but also $z \not\in H$, a contradiction.

Note that I removed the case for when $y = 1$, but that case follows similarly. So, for your example, $B(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}) = (0, \frac{1}{2})$, we have that $(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{2}) \subseteq K \setminus H \cap (0, \frac{1}{2})$ (giving us that $B(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$ is not contained in $H$).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive and clear explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The set $H$ does not contain the ball $B_{(1/4, 1/4)}$.

$$H=\left[{1\over2},{3\over4}\right]\cup\left[{1\over3},{11\over24}\right]\cup\left[{1\over4},{5\over16}\right]\cup\cdots.$$

In particular, $H$ does not contain $\displaystyle{11.5\over24}$.

It took me some time to see this, and it would have been nice if the author had helped out a little more!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that $B(1/4;1/4)$ is contained in $H$.

Consider a visual of the set. I've highlighted the intervals in the union in Desmos:

[image]

The areas shaded in purple are the intervals
$$
\left[ \frac 1 n , \frac 1 n + \frac{1}{2^n} \right] \text{, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$}
$$
Clearly, there are gaps between them all. And, if I choose to overlay $B(1/4;1/4) = (0,1/2)$ in red, we see it falls into those gaps:

[image]

You could probably use this idea to motivate a formal proof by picking some $x$ in the gaps and showing it is not in the union, by showing it is not in any of the intervals forming $H$.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me visualize the problem in question!